# Instantiate non-activity class on pending intent in android

Tags: java, android

i have a notification in android, and i want to do something like

MyStaticClass.start() when i click in the notification, this class is not an activity, its only to instantiate a needed class.

How can i do it it?

This is my actually code:

```
String notificationContent = "Hay una nueva version disponible";
        String notificationTitle = "Firext";
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(FirextApplication.getInstance().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirextApplication.getInstance(), UpdateProcess.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(FirextApplication.getInstance(), 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) FirextApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                FirextApplication.getInstance())
                .setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
                .setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker(notificationTitle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify((int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), notification);
```

And the class i need to call

```
public class UpdateProcess {

    private static final String APPLICATION_VND_ANDROID_PACKAGE_ARCHIVE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    private static final String NEWVERSION = "NewVersion.apk";
    private static final File EX = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    private static volatile UpdateProcess instance = null;
    private Activity activity;


    private UpdateProcess(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        checkForNewUpdates();
    }

    public static void startUpdate(Activity activity) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (UpdateProcess.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new UpdateProcess(activity);
                }
            }
        } else {
            UpdateProcess.instance.activity = activity;
        }
    }
```

I only need do a UpdateProcess.startUpdate();

Edit:

This is my new code:

```
private void showNot() {
        String notificationContent = "Hay una nueva version disponible";
        String notificationTitle = "Firext";
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(FirextApplication.getInstance().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        int smalIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirextApplication.getInstance(), UpdateProcess.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
                .setContentText(notificationContent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
                .setTicker(notificationTitle)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                //.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float, "Call", pendingIntent).build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder);
    }

public class UpdateProcess extends IntentService {

    private static final String APPLICATION_VND_ANDROID_PACKAGE_ARCHIVE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    private static final String NEWVERSION = "NewVersion.apk";
    private static final File EX = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    private static volatile UpdateProcess instance = null;
    private Context context;

    private UpdateProcess(Context context) {
        super("UpdateProcess");
        this.context = context;
        checkForNewUpdates();
    }

  @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        startUpdate(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

But when i do click in action nothing happens..i get thi error:

05-10 17:15:22.955     753-7617/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.firext.android/.util.UpdateProcess bnds=[192,346][1080,490] } U=0: not found

Edit 2. Now works, i forget include service in manifest

Comment: Do **not** put an `Activity` in a static data member. You are leaking memory.

Comment: I need to show a toast message in a method inside UpdateProcess, what i should use? Only a context, appllicationcontext,basecontext..? Im not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to show a toast message in a method inside UpdateProcess, what i should use?

Your `Notification` can trigger an `Activity`, a `Service`, or a `BroadcastReceiver` via its `PendingIntent`. `Activity` is a `Context`. `Service` is a `Context`. `BroadcastReceiver` receives a `Context` as a parameter to `onReceive()`. Hence, from all three locations, *you already have a `Context`*, so use that one.

You might also consider getting rid of the `Toast` entirely. A `Toast` is only good for a message that the user does not need, as the user might not see it.

> I only need do a UpdateProcess.startUpdate();

It would appear that `checkForNewUpdates()` will do some significant work.

If that work will take less than ~15 seconds, convert `UpdateProcess` to `UpdateIntentService`, extending `IntentService`, and do your `checkForNewUpdates()` work in `onHandleIntent()`. You can use a `getService()` `PendingIntent` to trigger the `UpdateIntentService` to do its work.

If the work is likely to take longer than that, you should consider using [the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) (or perhaps [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)), to ensure that the device stays awake long enough for your work to complete.

Comment: I will update my class to IntentService and delete the activity field, thanks!

Comment: @colymore: You commented out your use of the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: With this without the // its same result..dont start..And i add an action with the pendingintent but anyone works

Comment: @colymore: Look at LogCat to see if you have complaints, such as missing the `<service>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use getActivity() use getService() in you pending intent. Create an ad-hoc intent service to call UpdateProcess.startUpdate() in onHandleIntent(). In this case you can't use an activity as parameter of course, but maybe you can change the parameter in a Context.